# Go to selected string after 'find' in sublime text

Tags: find, sublimetext3

After finding a string in a single file using the sublime 'find' field. is there a key command to begin editing that selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After finding a string you want - just press 'ESC' button and you will be able to edit that selection.

Hope it helps.